# Virtualize all cpu cores on a guest with a virtual single core

Tags: virtualization, transparent

Suppose that we have a guest OS that allows support only for a single core.
We have an host with N=2^K cores with a virtualization solution that allows to provide all such cores to our guest.
The guest will see only one core while using most of the computational resources of host's N cores.

Is it possible, with actual technologies, to have such a transparent allocation of CPU cores to guest?

Regards,
Giovanni

P.S. [Found an old answer to this question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/17101)

Comment: What you're asking for is equivalent to an automatic code parallelizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Such technology does not exist ATM.  If it did, everyone would be using it.